# how to handle run time error 5174 in excel if the file not present in the directory?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I need to check whether a file is present in the directory.

If file NOT present i should create a new one.

But at run time the Excel gives an error;

> "Run-time error 5174: Application defined or object defined error".

Is there any exception handling technique in VBA to catch these run time error?

How can i overcome this issue so that i can create a file if non existant?

```
Dim savename, FileExt, FileName As String
Dim i, finalrow As Integer
Dim wdvar As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document

Set wdvar = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdvar.Visible = True         

FileName = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Report.docx"
Set wrdDoc = wdvar.Documents.Open(FileName)

With wdvar
    .Visible = True
    .Activate


   .Documents.Add
```

Answer (score 1):

add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime and use the Scripting.FilesystemObject.
It has a nice handy "FileExists()" function that you can use to test if a file exists.

```
   Dim fso as new Scripting.FileSystemobject

   If (fso.FileExists(strPath)) Then
      debug.print "File Exists"
   Else
      debug.print "File Not Found"
   End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The error handling can be done like this:

```
sub Main
Dim savename, FileExt, FileName As String
Dim i, finalrow As Integer
Dim wdvar As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document

On Error GoTo Main_Error

Set wdvar = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdvar.Visible = True         

FileName = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Report.docx"
Set wrdDoc = wdvar.Documents.Open(FileName)

With wdvar
    .Visible = True
    .Activate


   .Documents.Add
'...
on error goto 0
exit sub
Main_error
   if err.number = 5174 then
   'you may write something here
else
   'normally a msgbox for the error 
end if
end sub
```

Additionally 1: if you want to create the file, you may do it from the error handler or you can simply check whether the file is existing. Depends what you want: -> http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win003.htm

Additionally 2: 
do not use integers, but use long, and declare each variable on a separate line, otherwise you declare them as vars.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I use this function :

```
Public Function File_Exist(sFilePath As String) As Boolean
    Dim sProv As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        sProv = Dir(sFilePath, vbDirectory)

        File_Exist = (sProv <> "")
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox prompt:="Error on test file= " & sFilePath & vbCrLf & _
           Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
End Function
```

---

Where do you need to use it :

```
If File_Exist(Filename) Then
    Set wrdDoc = wdvar.Documents.Open(Filename)
Else
    With wdvar
        .Visible = True
        .Activate

       .Documents.Add
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Use the Scripting.FileSystemObject instead. it has a nice FileExists() function. Much cleaner than using the old Dir function.

Comment: @JoeBourne : Sure, but you don't need to load references to use `Dir` so it's much easier to share with others! ;)

Comment: the Op is late binding the "Word.Application" so could easily late bind the scripting.filesystemobject as well - no real need to add the reference, but its lazy not to.